# How to properly connect client application to Scylla or Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

Let's say I have a cluster of 3 nodes for ScyllaDB in my local network (it can be AWS VPC).
I have my Java application running in the same local network.

I am concerned how to properly connect app to DB.

- Do I need to specify all 3 IP addresses of DB nodes for the app?
- What if over time one or several nodes die and get resurrected on other IPs? Do I have to manually reconfigure application?
- How is it done properly in big real production cases with tens of DB servers, possibly in different data centers?

I would be much grateful for a code sample of how to connect Java app to multi-node cluster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify contact points (you can use DNS names instead of IPs) - several nodes (usually 2-3), and driver will connect to one of them, and will discover the all nodes of the cluster after connection (see the [driver's documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.10/manual/core/#cql-session)).  After connection is established, driver keeps the separate [control connection](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.10/manual/core/control_connection/) opened, and via it receives the information about nodes that are going up & down, joining or leaving the cluster, etc., so it's able to keep information about cluster topology up-to-date.

If you're specifying DNS names instead of the IP addresses, then it's better to specify configuration parameter `datastax-java-driver.advanced.resolve-contact-points` as `true` (see [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.10/manual/core/configuration/reference/)), so the names will be resolved to IPs on every reconnect, instead of resolving at the start of application.

Answer (score 1):

Alex Ott's answer is correct, but I wanted to add a bit more background so that it doesn't look arbitrary.

The selection of the 2 or 3 nodes to connect to is described at
https://docs.scylladb.com/kb/seed-nodes/

However, going forward, Scylla is looking to move away from differentiating between Seed and non-Seed nodes. So, in future releases, the answer will likely be different. Details on these developments at:
https://www.scylladb.com/2020/09/22/seedless-nosql-getting-rid-of-seed-nodes-in-scylla/

Comment: Does Scylla care if nodes specified as connection endpoints are seed nodes?  That sounds odd to me.

Comment: No, it does not. Seed nodes are important for server->server communication (less so in newer versions), not for client->server communications.

Comment: The phrase "Seed nodes" is not relevant to the original question. "Seed nodes" is an implementation detail inside Scylla, which is relevant to how new nodes in the Scylla cluster learn about each others. Clients do not care about the "seed node" concept at all. They may connect to any one of the extant Scylla nodes and learn about all the rest. That being said, the client does need a way to find at least one such node, and Scylla does not tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the specific questions:

> Do I need to specify all 3 IP addresses of DB nodes for the app?

No.  Your app just needs one to work.  But it might not be a bad idea to have a few, just in case one is down.

> What if over time one or several nodes die and get resurrected on other IPs?

As long as your app doesn't stop, it maintains its own version of gossip.  So it will see the new nodes being added and connect to them as it needs to.

> Do I have to manually reconfigure application?

If you're specifying IP addresses, yes.

> How is it done properly in big real production cases with tens of DB servers, possibly in different data centers?

By abstracting the need for a specific IP, using something like [Consul](https://www.consul.io/).  If you wanted to, you could easily build a simple restful service to expose an inventory list or even the results of `nodetool status`.